# Pass Method ( of void return type and with no input arguments) as parameter using C#

Tags: c#, generics, c#-3.0, delegates

I want to pass a method ( of void return type and with no input arguments)  as parameter using C#. Below is my sample code. How can I do it ?

```
public void Method1()
{
    ... do something
}

public int Method2()
{
    ... do something 
}

public void RunTheMethod([Method Name passed in here] myMethodName)
{

    myMethodName();
    ... do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System.Action will fit the bill:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

You've also got various generic versions of Action for methods that have parameters but have a void return type, and Func for methods that return something.

So your RunTheMethod method would look like

```
public void RunTheMethod(Action myMethod)
{
    myMethod();
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
RunTheMethod(Method1);
RunTheMethod(Method2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you can use delegates – in your case, you could use `System.Action` to do exactly that.

```
public void RunTheMethod(System.Action myMethodName)
{

    myMethodName();
    ... do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which act like a pointer to a method

Comment: Not quite code - but I think essential read so you can understand (actually there is some code in there) - http://www.vwd-cms.com/Forum/Forums.aspx?topic=13

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get a solution to your query. They basically serve as a pointer or reference to a function.

Also take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Cs_delegates101_practical.aspx) example for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Delegate     
public delegate void OnDoStuff();

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Pass any of the method name here 
                Invoker(Method1);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static void Invoker(OnDoStuff method)
            {
                method.Invoke();
            }

            private static void Method1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method1 from method " + i);
            }

            private static void Method2()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method2 from method " + i);
            }

            private static void Method3()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Method3 from method " + i);
            }
        }
```